# Scala test problem with Eclipse, not possible to run it

Tags: eclipse, scala, unit-testing

I'm working on a school project that requires some tests.
We have some ressources to build our tests correctly with Eclipse
The first time I've run the tests, all was fine but now it's crashing everytime, the trace is the next one :

```
java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(CoderResult.java:281)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:339)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
at scala.io.BufferedSource$BufferedLineIterator.hasNext(BufferedSource.scala:70)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:447)
at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:929)
at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:929)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1417)
at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq$(Growable.scala:50)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:104)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to(TraversableOnce.scala:310)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to$(TraversableOnce.scala:308)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1417)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:302)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer$(TraversableOnce.scala:302)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1417)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:289)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray$(TraversableOnce.scala:283)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1417)
at scala.tools.eclipse.scalatest.launching.ScalaTestLauncher$.main(ScalaTestLauncher.scala:12)
at scala.tools.eclipse.scalatest.launching.ScalaTestLauncher.main(ScalaTestLauncher.scala)
```

My last search have not show any good results
I tried to see the encoding
and the other results seemed to be about a file reading problem

If someone had ever see this same problem

Comment: Eclipse support for **Scala** is deprecated. I would suggest you to switch to Intellij or to VScode. BTW, you can always just run the tests on the terminal using your build tool instead of depending on a GUI to do everything.